# What happens if I connect computer to phone with aux connectors and just put music on each?

Tags: audio, cellphone

If I connect an aux cable, like that one:
https://5.imimg.com/data5/OG/IB/MY-9820141/aux-cord-for-audio-500x500.jpg

Between my computer and phone, and start playing music on both of them, what will happen? Will there be current flowing back and forth, from either the computer or the phone? Can it be dangerous?

Will the answer change if instead the cable above is connected to a computer on one side, but on the other side is connected to a USB-C to aux adapter, while the adapter is connected by USB-C to the phone?

Comment: Why would you connect two outputs together? It makes no sense. Usually nothing breaks, but this is not guaranteed.

Comment: Exactly. It makes no sense, but one could still do it. This isn't idiot proof, hence my question what would happen.

Comment: "What would happen"? The CD tray will open and a robotic arm bearing a rolled up newspaper will unfurl and swat the misbehaving user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there will be a flow of current between the two devices and it might or might not harm one or both devices. I would *suppose* that nothing breaks, **but you can't be sure because this is not a specified use case.**
This does not change with the use of a USB-C to AUX adapter. It still depends on the roughness of both audio outputs.

The resulting signal on the wire depends on the output impedance of both sound outputs. Probably one output has higher driving capabilites than the other one and saturates that one. The signal from this stronger output would be the signal remaining on the line, maybe a little bit attenuated.

If the output on the computer has a headphone amplifier build in, it is probably going to "win" this fight. If it is the normal audio out jack there is no way to tell which one is stronger. You have to check the datasheets of the specific products. But for that you obviously have to know what audio driver the computer / smartphone / USB-adapter uses.

Answer (score 1):

Stuff could break, loudspeaker outputs operate a higher power and are more likely to be damaged (and do damage) and headphone outputs are designed to withstand brief short-circuits, but that does not mean that they will survive this sort of abuse.

connecting outputs to outputs is always risky, if you want both devices to drive the same speaker (or headphones) use an audio mixer. either physical hardware mixer, or plug the phone into the computer's audio in and use the computers software controlled sound mixer to combine the sounds.